# UILabel's text loads after delay

Tags: ios, queue, grand-central-dispatch

In my code I am calling this

```
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    if (responseData != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *dataSource = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
        [self.ticker1 loadData:dataSource];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error requesting timeline %@ with user info %@.", error, error.userInfo);
    }
}];
```

and in the `loadData:` method I do this

```
NSDictionary *dict = [dataSource objectAtIndex:0];

_label.text = [dict objectForKey:@"text"];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.ios.task", NULL);
dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[dict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    dispatch_async(main, ^{
        _image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});

dispatch_release(queue);
```

The problem is the image I load on main queue loads much faster than `_label.text` is being set. It gets set after a long delay of about 4-5 seconds. I would like to know why this is happening. Is it because the `main queue` is not being released or something on that lines?

Comment: If im not wrong certain images file size is too big and thus taking a longer period of time like what you mentioned 4~5seconds

Comment: Image loading with a delay is fine but the problem is that the text loads after the image in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell from your code which thread the request's handler block is being called on, but if it's not the main thread, that could be the problem.

Try setting the label's text property from within a

```
dispatch_async(main, ^{
    _label.text = [dict objectForKey:@"text"];
});
```

block.

Comment: I tried that already and it works fine. So does that mean the main thread is busy with something and hence there is a delay? But why would it take so long to release the main thread? It doesn't show any trace in the debug under main thread, so not sure what operations are being performed

Answer (score 0):

The weirdest thing fixed this problem for me. I made the label hight fixed and slightly bigger then it should be, in the storyboard. It made a yellow warning in the constraints, but at least the label is loading.